# Adding constraints in XCode makes UIImageView take up whole screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do you prevent a UIImageView from resizing after adding a constraint to align horizontally to the center? Every time I run the program with the restraints in place the image that was originally sized 300x300 takes up the entire screen

Comment: What is the contentMode of your UIImageView? Also, it would be good to show some of your code and a screenshot

Comment: The constraints must uniquely define size and position of the view -- the image doesn't determine the view's size if the constraint is doing that.  Then content mode says how to adapt the image to view's size.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as an image view comes under control of auto layout, its size is determined by its image — unless you take measures to prevent that. For example, you can add width and height constraints, or you can add external top-and-bottom and leading-and-trailing constraints that set the size relative to the superview or whatever.

(By the way, the very first thing you should always do is examine your interface in the View Debugger. If you really added only a constraint to align horizontally to the center, that is an error — an insufficient constraint — and the View Debugger will let you know of that fact.)